# Performance Issue in ng-options using custom filter in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I am facing a performance issue. I am using custom filters in ng-options which is under ng-repeat.

Below the sample code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<select ng-model="User[item.id]" ng-options="translatedKey.option as translatedKey.value|optionTranslater for translatedKey in item.translatedKeys">
</div>
```

In my Controller $scope.items is defined which contain 100 fields.
In every Item ,item.translatedKeys contain 1 to 500 fields.

Now my problem is in every $digest optionTranslater is being called 100*500 times approx.

It leads the page slow. I have to use the custom filter in my dynamic page.In my custom filter I am also use angular translator .

Could anyone suggest a better solution which do the performance better .

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Use one way binding in ng_repeat

Answer (score 0):

Angular runs every single filter (including the date filter) twice per $digest cycle once something has changed. This takes it's toll on the performance. The first run is from the $$watchers detecting any changes, the second run is to see if there are further changes that need updated values.

If you can change your DOM filter to use a $filter provider, which you can use to run filters in your controller before parsing them into the DOM you preprocess your data before sending it to the view, which avoids the step of parsing the DOM and understanding the inline filter syntax. This would probably increase the performance. It would go something like this:

```
$scope.translatedKey = $filter('optionTranslater')($scope.translatedKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

If item.translatedKeys are static, I would suggest one-time binding like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<select ng-model="User[item.id]" ng-options="translatedKey.option as translatedKey.value|optionTranslater for translatedKey in ::item.translatedKeys">
</div>
```

-> the options will be rendered only once per each select. Not everytime in $digest cycle.

---

You can combine this with the translations in controller as described in answer above. -> you will get even faster result.
Now all options are translated as many times as there are selects.